# Request attribute not passed from Action to JSP

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts1

I have a JSP page which displays tabular data retrieved from database on page load. Every row in the table has a "more" button in last column which opens a modal window displaying detailed information of the record. In this modal window I have a button. On click of this button I want to display the audit history for the record in a new modal window.
My JSP file contains the Ajax call to retrieve the audit details details of the particular record.

```
function showHistoryLog() {
    var questionId = document.getElementById("txtQuestionId").innerText;

    var url = "myAction.do?dispatchMethodName=getAuditTrail&questionId="+questionId; 

    $.ajax({
    method : "GET",
    url : url,
    data : questionId
    }).done(function(msg) {
        alert("Record retrieved successfully.");
        $('#detmyAudit').modal('show');
    });

    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

Action file contains code to retrieve parameters from ajax call and then call subsequent service method which returns list of records (Audit history records).
I am setting this list as attribute in request object:

```
request.setAttribute("MyList", myList);
```

When I try to access this attribute in my JSP, it is undefined.

```
<tbody>
        <logic:notEmpty name="MyList">
```

this is is always empty. However, in my action class this has 1 record.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Having the relevant code and exact error message will allow others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is the answer. I created a JSON object and set it to set response object in my Action file.

```
String myJsonObj = createJSONObject(myList);
setReponseObj(response, myJsonObj, "text/html");
```

Accessed this JSON object in my JSP. Function showHistoryLog is now changed to:

```
function showHistoryLog() {

    var questionId = document.getElementById("txtQuestionId").innerText;

    var url = "myAction.do?dispatchMethodName=getAuditTrail&questionId="+questionId; 

    if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#tblmyAudit' ) ) {
        var auditTable = $('#tblmyAudit').dataTable().api();
        auditTable.destroy();
    }

    $('#tblmyAudit').DataTable( {
        ajax: {
        url: url,
        dataSrc: 'data'
        },
        columns: [
              { data: "QuestionId" },
              { data: "Question" },
              { data: "Answer" },
              { data: "UpdatedBy" },
              { data: "UpdatedDate" }
          ],
        "scrollX": true,

    } );

    $('#detmyAudit').modal('show');
}
```